# Ubuntu 14.04 inkscape problem

Tags: inkscape

In terminal :

```
nebojsa@nebojsaDesktop:~$ inkscape
The program 'inkscape' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

and then :

```
nebojsa@nebojsaDesktop:~$ sudo apt-get install inkscape
[sudo] password for nebojsa: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
inkscape is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

inkscape wont run, any one know what is the problem?

Comment: If you open a terminal and type `inkscape` does it give you any error messages?

Comment: no only that what im wrote, that is from terminal, in soft.manager inkscape shows installed but no way to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your rep list is not update, so before installing inskape update it using this command : `sudo apt-get update`

if it does't work ,add inskcape ppa to your ubuntu using this command :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
```

update your apt :

```
apt-get update
```

and install :

```
sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

Comment: i tried but same thing

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
nebojsa@nebojsaDesktop:~$ sudo apt-get install inkscape
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
inkscape is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.
nebojsa@nebojsaDesktop:~$

Comment: nebojsa@nebojsaDesktop:~$ inkscape
The program 'inkscape' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install inkscape
nebojsa@nebojsaDesktop:~$

Comment: I found solution, i delete ppa repository for inkscape (launchpad), and reinstall inkscape. Work fine.

Comment: @sparkmood I faced this problem too and I tried `sudo dpkg -r inkscape` then remove ppa using y-ppa manager and cleaned up my file system, And again i installed Inkscape using **sparkmood's** guide. But no luck it says **The program 'inkscape' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:**
`sudo apt-get install inkscape`. Any idea Sir?